# How to create a macOS Sierra iso installer successfully?

Tags: command-line, macos, utilities, iso

I want to test Sierra before fully installing it on my computer by creating a Sierra iso installer, which I can use on Virtual Box. When I attempt the first step below (mount the installer image) I get an error from hdutil that the resource is busy. Does anyone have suggestions on how to safely do this?

> error: hdiutil: attach failed - Resource busy

steps:

1. Mount the installer image

   ```
   hdiutil attach /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg -noverify - nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/install_app
   ```
2. Convert the boot image to a sparse bundle

   ```
   hdiutil convert /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.dmg -format UDSP -o /tmp/Sierra
   ```
3. Increase the sparse bundle capacity to accommodate the packages

   ```
   hdiutil resize -size 8g /tmp/Sierra.sparseimage
   ```
4. Mount the sparse bundle for package addition

   ```
   hdiutil attach /tmp/Sierra.sparseimage -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/install_build
   ```
5. Remove Package link and replace with actual files

   ```
   rm /Volumes/install_build/System/Installation/Packages cp -rp /Volumes/install_app/Packages /Volumes/install_build/System/Installation/
   ```
6. Unmount the installer image

   ```
   hdiutil detach /Volumes/install_app
   ```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have a look at my answer, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253640/install-sierra-as-guest-os-in-vm-with-parallels-12/253644?s=2|0.4333#253644 and make sure that the InstallESD.dmg and BaseSystem.dmg files are not mounted before running the script.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm not sure how to check for that (first time making an ISO). When I ran your script I got this error:  `christinas-MacBook-Pro:shell_scripts christina$ ./makeSierraISO
hdiutil: attach failed - Resource busy
.............................................................................................................................
created: /Users/christina/shell_scripts/macOS_Sierra_10.12.0.cdr.dmg
/dev/disk4           Apple_partition_scheme          
`

Comment: `/dev/disk4s1         Apple_partition_map             
/dev/disk4s2         Apple_HFS                       /Volumes/iso
Validating target...done
Could not recognize "/Volumes/esd/BaseSystem.dmg" as an image file
Could not get source volume name
rm: /Volumes/OS X Base System/System/Installation/Packages: No such file or directory
cp: /Volumes/esd/Packages: No such file or directory
cp: directory /Volumes/OS X Base System does not exist
hdiutil: detach failed - No such file or directory
`

Comment: Before you run the script InstallESD.dmg and BaseSystem.dmg cannot already be mounted. Open Disk Utility and if mounted eject them, then run the script.

Comment: The script now runs, but the installer doesn't work in the iso. When I start virtual box, it returns a black screen.

Comment: I no longer use VirtualBox as it never really supported OS X/macOS as good as VMware Fusion does, so I really can't offer any help with VB. The script I pointed you to creates a bootable installer image that works in VMware Fusion and Parallels Desktop, so theoretically it should also work in VirtualBox. That said, as bad as VirtualBox was at running OS X, I wouldn't waist my time with it even just to evaluate, I'd use VMware Fusion or Parallels Desktop. Even then, not all features are supported in a VM but you'd get a better evaluation then with VB. Both VMware & Parallels have free trials.

Comment: success! "some people encountered black screen upon booting the virtual machine. They reported that changing the default chipset ICH9 to PIIX3 fixes this issue."  from this article: http://ntk.me/2012/09/07/os-x-on-os-x/

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue when I upgraded to Sierra. Adding -force flag resolved issue. Try **hdiutil detach -force /Volumes/install_app** it might work.